# create nested array for web service in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

First, im a beginner in PHP so please bear with me.

I want to create something like this JSON array :

```
{
children: [
{
id: "1"
user_id: "1"
name: "Test"
gender: "M"
born_date: "2014-10-01"
born_hour: "12:12:12"
hospital: "test hospital"
}-
}-
{
id: "2"
user_id: "1"
name: "test2"
gender: "F"
born_date: "2014-10-06"
born_hour: null
hospital: null
}-
]
result: "true"
total: 2
}
```

To make my question easier, this is an easy to read JSON i want to create (**you can think mobiles as children** in my case) :

[image]

The `children` should become the parent and array. This is what i accomplished so far :

```
{
0: {
children: {
id: "1"
user_id: "1"
name: "Test"
gender: "M"
born_date: "2014-10-01"
born_hour: "12:12:12"
hospital: "test hospital"
}-
}-
1: {
children: {
id: "2"
user_id: "1"
name: "test2"
gender: "F"
born_date: "2014-10-06"
born_hour: null
hospital: null
}-
}-
result: "true"
total: 2
}
```

The children is not the parent of the items and not in array ([]).

This is my code to generate the above JSON :

```
$resultArray = array('result' => 'true', 'total' => $size);

            foreach($result as $child)
            {
                if($child)
                {
                    //add to array
                    $resultArray[] = array('children' => array('id' => $child['id'], 
                    'user_id' => $child['user_id'], 
                    'name' => $child['name'], 
                    'gender' => $child['gender'],
                    'born_date' => $child['born_date'], 
                    'born_hour' => $child['born_hour'],
                    'hospital' => $child['hospital']));
                }
            }

            $this->response($resultArray, 200);
```

Please kindly help me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just buil the array first, push all items etc. Then finally put that parent key on the end and put the gathered array inside that:

```
foreach($result as $child) {
    if($child) {
        // so build it first
        $resultArray[] = array(
            'id' => $child['id'], 
            'user_id' => $child['user_id'], 
            'name' => $child['name'], 
            'gender' => $child['gender'],
            'born_date' => $child['born_date'], 
            'born_hour' => $child['born_hour'],
            'hospital' => $child['hospital']
        );
    }
}
// end then finally, put it inside the parent key children
$resultArray = array('result' => 'true', 'total' => $size, 'children' => $resultArray);
$this->response($resultArray, 200);
```

Comment: Im trying this now. Thanks

Comment: @BlazeTama okay no prob, i hope this does well for you

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will accept your answer in 4 mins (the system's rule)

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'json_encode' function.

```
$resultArray = json_encode($result);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Sorry i think we have some miss-understanding. The JSON has benn encoded. Thanks anyway